# how to ask a follow up question in the "answer space" of the same question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I want to ask a follow up question.

Is there any possibility to paste code in the comment section of the same question ?

It would be nice to have such option.

Comment: A follow up question to a question you have asked yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the question is very closely related, or an expansion on the information you've already provided, use the edit feature to add it to the question.

However, if the question is about something unrelated to your initial problem (like you solve one error, and hit another one later in the code), then please open a new question.

In your case, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15250510/1069068) appears to be the question in question. As other users pointed out, it is an almost exact duplicate of your older question. For such cases, the edit option is what you want.

Comment: *If* the new question is legitimately posted as a new question, it's probably not a bad idea to add a sentence explaining that it's separate from, but related to your other question (and link to the old one for context).

Comment: But if the new question questions the old question in question, then the questions of this user become questionable, at best.

Comment: @Telthien Your comment is far too questioning.

Comment: Unquestionably.